# How to show that $a^2+a+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to show that $a^2+a+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, where $p$ is an odd prime and $ord_p a=3$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $a^3-1=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)$, so if $a^3\equiv 1$, then...